# Unable to replicate the couch db

Tags: couchdb, replication, database-replication

I have two machines lets say 156 and 157
I have a db in 156 machine which i want to replicate to 157 machine for that i am using the following command

```
curl -X POST -d '{"source":"http://couch_user:couch_password@XX.XX.XX.156:5984/root_openwhisk-156_whisks","target":"http://couch_user:couch_password@XX.XX.XX.157:5984/root_openwhisk-156_whisks"}' http://couch_user:couch_password@XX.XX.XX.156:5984/_replicate -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

also i tried without password

```
curl -X POST -d '{"source":"http://XX.XX.XX.156:5984/root_openwhisk-156_whisks","target":"http://XX.XX.XX.157:5984/root_openwhisk-156_whisks"}' http://XX.XX.XX.156:5984/_replicate -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

but i am getting below error 
{"error":"db_not_found","reason":"could not open http://XX.XX.XX.156:5984/root_openwhisk-156_whisks/"}

I have also tried the replicator utility in futon but that also doesn't work

In the Futon i can see root_openwhisk-156_whisks along with _replicator and _user in both machine
Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

The source should be just `root_openwhisk-156_whisks` without the http protocol, IP and login credentials. Example from the official documents: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/replication.html [image]

Comment: Actually you can the complete URL that is no the issue. Issue here was some special character was there in the command